# How to correctly retrieve data?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've done a list that shows titles, when i click on an item is opened an activity that shows the description of the element; i'm getting this description using the id of the element.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String  descrizione=mydb.getDescription(id+1,titolo.getText().toString());

        }
```

This is the method in my database:

```
public String getDescription(long id,String formulario)
{
    String descrizione="NADA";
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from "+formulario+" where id="+id+"", null );
    if(res!=null && res.getCount()>0){
        res.moveToFirst();
        descrizione = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("Descrizione"));
        res.close();
    }
    return descrizione;
}
```

THE PROBLEM: when i delete an element all the description result shifted forward. I don't know if the problem is with the cursor, the item's id acquisition or with the delete method... any help is valued

This is my delete method:

```
public Integer deleteFormula (String formula, String formulario)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(formulario, "Formule = ? ", new String[] { formula});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, when you want to show database data in a ListView, you should use CursorAdapter to bind database data with your ListView.  From the code you've posted, can't tell whether and how it's been implemented. If you have  any doubts  about it I suggest you look into this article  which explains this subject very well https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter

Secondly, when you successfully bind the data to your ListView, then in onItemClick method  you can use the second parameter which is View and represents the clicked ListView row , to retrieve the data that is shown in that row.

Thirdly, when you delete a row from your database table, you should synchronize  your  ListView by  getting  a new cursor and calling your CursorAdapter changeCursor method with new cursor as argument.

This is just a rough sketch, but I hope it will help at least a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is using position to determine **id** in :-

`String  descrizione=mydb.getDescription(id+1,titolo.getText().toString());`

At first, assuming 3 columns inserted:-

First column has an id of 1, 2nd 2 and 3rd 3. So initially if rows are sorted according to id (good chance of this happening but no guarantee) then position 0 (first row displayed) + 1, will display data for id 1, position (2nd item in the List) 1 will show data for id 2 etc and all looks good.

However if you delete id 2 then:-

- The 1st item in the list will display data from id 1 and position 0 still equates to id 1.
- However the 2nd Item in the list will display data from the table for row id 3 BUT position 1 + 1 = 2 so the wrong id is calculated.

In short you cannot use position to correlate to the id.

You need to somehow get the appropriate row. Perhaps the easiest solution is to use a CursorAdapater, then id will be the id (column name must be **_id**).

Comment: So if i show the row id in the list view(with an invisible textview maybe), i can access the correct id when i need it? Is this a possibility?

Comment: It's not whether or not the row id is assigned to a view or not. The issue is how to get enough information to be able to correctly identify the row being clicked from within the onClick listener.

Answer (score 0):

Cursor adapter would be the optimal solution. But if you want to stick with the same code when you delete a row from your database table you must ensure that you also get the updated list of data from your database.

And also you don't have to add + 1 to this code. If you have to add + 1 it means you're doing things wrong.

```
String  descrizione=mydb.getDescription(id+1,titolo.getText().toString());
```

This would work well if you are just constantly updating your list with the data from your database whenever there are changes, and id doesn't represent the databaseID as it represents the ID of the view within the adapter.